# Autodesk Platform Services - Viewer: How do I make the camera normal to a selected face on the part?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, aps

I am trying to create a feature where the user can click the face of a model in the viewer and the camera will orient itself normal to the selected face.

The approach I followed was was capturing the details of the normal of the face from the viewer.hitTest(), the setting the camera at a point along this normal targeted at the original clicked point using  the setPosition() method. I noticed however this was not working with some models. On further inspection I noticed that the face normal reported by the hitTest() was in a different coordinate system compared to the camera.
I am trying to create a feature where the user can click the face of a model in the viewer and the camera will orient itself normal to the selected face. The approach I followed was was capturing the details of the normal of the face from the viewer.hitTest(), the setting the camera at a point along this normal targeted at the original clicked point using the setPosition() method. I noticed however this was not working with some models. On further inspection I noticed that the face normal reported by the hitTest() was in a different coordinate system compared to the camera.
[For the same direction camera and face normal report in different coordinate systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAVxd.png) The models source is a .dwfx file generated from an inventor .iam file Is there another approach I could try that would work regardless if the coordinate systems line up or not? Or is there a way to find out the difference in rotations of the coordinate systems programmatically?

Comment: Could you provide a sample file ?

Comment: https://titancompltd-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mba_design_titan_co_in/ERUFkWEo62JAsCUABXgxOMYB7oL-F8mafNFjYQOP38_rQg?e=6QFJYM

Answer (score 1):

From these 2 answers([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763825/autodesk-forge-viewer-get-local-position-of-fragment),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376706/controlling-camera-in-forge-viewer)), i got the cameraview to face the fragid.

```
function getApproximatePosition(model, fragid) {
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    let bbox = new THREE.Box3();
    frags.getWorldBounds(fragid, bbox);
    return bbox.getCenter();
}
let pos = getApproximatePosition(viewer.model,fragid)
let t = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1)
viewer.navigation.setView (pos, t)
```